# Python saying "no module named tflearn" but i imported it

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tflearn

I used Pip install TFlearn and ran my code on my Raspberry Pi but it says

> no module named tflearn

video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wypVcNIH6D4&t=3s

code:

```py
import nltk 
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer =  LancasterStemmer()

import numpy
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import random
import json

{"intents": [
        {"tag": "greeting",
         "patterns": ["Hi", "How are you", "Is anyone there?", "Hello", "Good day", "Whats up"],
         "responses": ["Hello!", "Good to see you again!", "Hi there, how can I help?"],
         "context_set": ""
        },
        {"tag": "goodbye",
         "patterns": ["cya", "See you later", "Goodbye", "I am Leaving", "Have a Good day"],
         "responses": ["Sad to see you go :(", "Talk to you later", "Goodbye!"],
         "context_set": ""
        },
        {"tag": "age",
         "patterns": ["how old", "how old is tim", "what is your age", "how old are you", "age?"],
         "responses": ["I am 18 years old!", "18 years young!"],
         "context_set": ""
        },
        {"tag": "name",
         "patterns": ["what is your name", "what should I call you", "whats your name?"],
         "responses": ["You can call me Tim.", "I'm Tim!", "I'm Tim aka Tech With Tim."],
         "context_set": ""
        },
        {"tag": "shop",
         "patterns": ["Id like to buy something", "whats on the menu", "what do you reccommend?", "could i get something to eat"],
         "responses": ["We sell chocolate chip cookies for $2!", "Cookies are on the menu!"],
         "context_set": ""
        },
        {"tag": "hours",
         "patterns": ["when are you guys open", "what are your hours", "hours of operation"],
         "responses": ["We are open 7am-4pm Monday-Friday!"],
         "context_set": ""
        }
   ]
}
```

Comment: How do you run your code?  Do you type `python myscript.py` on the command line, or do you use an IDE, or something else?

Comment: i did pip install tflearn

Comment: That's how you _installed the tflearn package_, but I asked how you _run your code_.

Answer (score 0):

Basic preliminary checks:
 run
    `pip freeze` to get a list of packages installed. Ideally tflearn should be there. If not, it indicates that the package has not been installed properly.